# App crashes when i apply style to a button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Here is the xml code of the `Button`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="1"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:background="@style/Buttoncomponentstyles" />
```

New here is my file which contains that style:

```
 <style name="Buttoncomponentstyles" parent="android:Widget.Button">
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/componentstyles_btn_default_holo_light</item>
 </style>
```

the drawable is at right place. 
below is my **logcat**:

```
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calculator/com.example.calculator.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #144: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #144: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:111)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at com.example.calculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    ... 11 more
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    ... 29 more
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0b0085 a=-1 r=0x7f0b0085}
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1968)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3338)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:591)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:103)
03-16 01:40:50.790: E/AndroidRuntime(27388):    ... 32 more
```

What is the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is the following line:

```
android:background="@style/Buttoncomponentstyles"
```

The [background accepts drawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3abackground), not style. The following should work:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="1"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:background="@drawable/componentstyles_btn_default_holo_light"/>
```

Comment: That way i would be able to add just one drawable how should go about adding drawables for different states of buttons.

Comment: Create a [selector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) (or State List, if you want to be fancy).

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you are using your style as background drawable and system is not able to cast Style to Drawable. Change your xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="@style/Buttoncomponentstyles"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="1"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />
```